# Why can't I send some UTF-8 characters to Firebase using the REST API?

Tags: rest, utf-8, firebase

I created a simple comment storage system on Firebase using the REST api in C++. I recently encountered a problem where the inclusion of Chinese characters would stop comments being uploaded. Here's an example of a packet that fails:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:10000
Accept: */*
User-Agent: CommentClient/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=0, max=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 198
Pragma: no-cache

{
    "CommentObject":
    {
        "Comment": "是",
        "Location": "X=1.000 Y=2.000 Z=3.000",
        "Rotation": "P=5.000000 Y=6.000000 R=4.000000",
        "Date": "2015.10.12-15.24.48",
        "Resolved": false
    }
}
```

I get two different errors when I try and send this packet.

Initially, I get Http Code 400 with the error: `error : Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names.`

When I make any subsequent requests prior to restarting the program, I get Http Code 405, with the error: `error: Unsupported request type`.

Is there something wrong with my requests? I can put identical data into Firebase through the Dashboard or using Vulcan. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: I think you need to show us your code, especially since you're working with C++.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's where things get a bit tricky. I'm doing this from Unreal Engine 4 using their built-in HttpRequest system (Which from what I can tell uses the curl library.) So the code is dispersed throughout a bunch of different classes, a lot of which I have no ability to change.

This is probably the most relevant code I could [show you](http://pastebin.com/MuNGDSWW), but I don't know how helpful that will be.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, for posterities sake, the problem was simply that one of the plugins I was using was setting the Content-Length header to the length of the string, which is fine if all your characters are one byte, as they would be with an ascii-style string, but once you start adding characters with multiple bytes, such as Chinese characters, the Content-Length would no longer match the actual number of bytes. The answer was simply to convert the string into utf-8 bytes and use the length of that array as the Content-Length.